# Unresolved external UrlCombineW

Tags: delphi, linker, linker-errors, c++builder, unresolved-external

I have a file which looks something like this:

```c++
#include <Shlwapi.h>
...
void SomeFunction()
{
UrlCombineW(...)
}
```

This compiled just fine until I installed another Delphi component in C++ Builder IDE but now reports unresolved external for `UrlCombineW`. The above call was fine before installing this component.

It seems that the component is overwriting this in some way so I need to explicitly tell the compiler where to look for `UrlCombineW`. This is a function from `Shlwapi.dll`.

Compiler does not complain, but how do I explicitly tell the linker where to look for this function and avoid unresolved external error?

Comment: Do you have `#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")` in your CPP file?  Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: @DavidM It helps and compiles now! Thanks. Can you please make it into an answer and explain what exactly this pragma does?

Comment: it instructs C++ to load external modules info from the description file `Shlwapi.lib`. That file contains either implementation of `UrlCombineW` or most probably reference that such implementation  can be taken during runtime from Windows unit ShlWapi.dll or some amnother one. You have to read manuals how to create and use DLLs for your C++ compiler. It looks strange, byt common sense this pragma should have been part of shlwapi.h itself if you did not made something exotic with pre-preprocessor define symbols. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Pragma_comment

Comment: `#pragma` is just one way to do this. Normally you'd pass the name of the .lib file to the linker. There will be options to do that in project config. That way is preferred over `#pragma` since it keeps compiler specific details out of the source code.

Comment: I don't use C++Builder but from what I can glean you should add the .lib file to the project using the project manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer.

You need to link to `Shlwapi.lib` in order for the linker to find the functions.  (This explanation glosses over a few things, but a `.lib`, a library file, can be either a [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) or [import](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Import_libraries) library.  A static library contains the functions themselves - it's basically a collection of .obj files bundled together; an import library says that functions X, Y and Z are found in a specific DLL.)  Either way, if you link the .lib in you will get the functions that you need.

There are a couple of ways to do tell the linker to link in the file:

- Use `#pragma comment(lib, "Filename.lib")` in a .cpp file somewhere.  For your case, this is `#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")`.
- Add it to the project options, which in turn adds it to the linker command line.  In C++ Builder you do this by actually adding the .lib file to the project, ie drag and drop it onto the project in the Project Manager, or use File > Add To Project.

Which you prefer is up to you.  I tend to link to localized things locally - so in my code, there's only one unit which uses `Shlwapi.h` and the fact it does so is an implementation detail hidden from the outside, it's not shown in the interface.  Therefore, in that file, I link using `#pragma comment` at the point I include the header.  On the other hand, if you have something used far more widely - to pick the widest example, kernel32.lib - I would add that the project itself.  (Note this is an example, you don't actually need to explicitly link to kernel32, that will be done for you!)